# Random Math Equation for an int

Tags: python, math, random

I'm trying to make something where it creates a random arithmetic equation equal to a predefined variable. For example:

```
sNum = 10
# Do something here
fNum = 3 * 2 - 3 + 7
fNum == sNum
True
```

I've tried thinking about ways to do this, but with no luck yet.

Constraints:

1. Only basic operators: `*`,  `+`,  `-`,  `/`
2. There can be any amount of operations performed, as long as the number of numbers in the equation is `>4` and `<10`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import random
sNum = 10

#Generate a database by randomly sampling the formulas space, save result into formula_result_dict:
formula_result_dict = {}
for m in range(100000):
    rand_len = np.random.randint(6) + 4
    op_pool = ['/','+','-','*']
    numbers = np.random.randint(1,100,rand_len) #Determine your range, here it's [1,99].
    rand_ops =  random.choices(op_pool, k=rand_len-1)
    str_to_eval = ''.join([str(numbers[k//2]) if k%2==0 else rand_ops[k//2] for k in range(rand_len-1+rand_len)])
    evaluated = eval(str_to_eval)
    if formula_result_dict.get(evaluated) is None:
        formula_result_dict[evaluated] = [str_to_eval]
    else:
        formula_result_dict[evaluated].append(str_to_eval)
        
#Now, let's say we want to generate a random formula, just pick a random formula from the relevant key:
formula = random.choice(formula_result_dict[sNum])
print(formula)
sNum == eval(formula)
```

Comment: Ive tried this and have tried printing both evaluated and sNum but they are not the same.
Ive gotten 198 for evaluated and 10 for sNum. Im not sure how the str_to_eval line works but it looks a bit complicated for me personally.

Comment: Oh, sorry. You wanted the random formula to be equal to sNum. My bad. I'll try and fix it.

Comment: Check the updated code above. It should work (w.h.p)